Solar Inverter vs DC
With, let's say a single phase, inverter with pulse width modulation which is essentially switching on and off the DC source at high frequency, then if the DC source is a battery when the switching is off there is no battery drain and the efficiency will be 95% or so.  However if that source is solar cells which produce steady DC power then during the switch off periods power solar goes unutilised? That leads me to the conclusion that the ac power that can be drawn is substantially less than the DC power that could be drawn directly? With a battery between the solar source and the inverter this problem is avoided. I suspect that there is something wrong with my logic here as it isn't mentioned anywhere?? But what?

you only asked but what? ... the rest of the "questions" are actually statements with incorrectly placed question marks ... please correct your post

Your grid connected solar inverter does far more than just on-off. Look up how a buck or boost converter works, and the role of capacitors on them.

you're right, but it's not that much power "left on the table". Look at MPPT (smps-based) vs PWM solar controller efficiency. Converting to AC doesn't lose as much as there are buffers in the power flow.

there's also 2 main types of inverter tech, low frequency and high frequency. With low frequency, you indeed have a point and that might be a consideration, but for high-frequency, it uses essentially a SMPS to step up the voltage before AC converstion, so that step should sop-up virtually all of the incoming power.

Thank you Winny and Dandavis for the helpful guidance and jsotola for the less than helpful pedantic grammar lesson! PS I hope my exclamation mark is ok.
